# Usar jquery sem refresh na pagina

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho esse jQuery e quando eu clico no botão ele atualiza com o resultado e da um refresh na pag,na vdd muda o link de teste/index.html para teste/index.html?,gostaria de saber se tem como fazer sem mudar sair da pag

```
<script>
$(function ($) {
    $('#enviar').click(function () {

        var linhas = $('#linhas').val();
        var plantas = $('#plantas').val();
        var combo = $('#haoum').val();

        var resultado = Number(linhas) + Number(plantas);
        $("#tam").attr("value", resultado);
        if (combo == "ha") {

        } else {

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<li><div class="tldate">Maio</div> </li>
<li>
      <div class="tl-circ"></div>
  <div class="timeline-panel">
    <div class="tl-heading">
      <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-669585">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#panel-343761" data-toggle="tab">Padrão</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#panel-530451" data-toggle="tab">Customizar</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-343761">
                    <p>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label" contenteditable="true">Espaçamento entre linhas(metros):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="1" id="linhas" value="1" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Espaçamento entre plantas(metros):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="plantas" placeholder="1" value="1" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label id="tamanho" class="control-label">Tamanho da área a ser plantada:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p><input type="text" class="input-mini" id="tam">         <select id="haoum" class="selectpicker">
                                                                            <option>ha</option>
                                                                            <option>m²</option>                                                                         
                                                                            </select></p>
             <div id="divPrincipal">

            </div>


            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

              <label>
                <button id="enviar" class="btn btn-default" >Estimar</button>
              </label>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-530451">
                    <p>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label" contenteditable="true">Espaçamento entre linhas(metros):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="1" id="linhas">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Espaçamento entre plantas(metros):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="plantas" placeholder="1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Tamanho da área a ser plantada:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p><input type="text" class="input-mini" id="tamanho">         <select class="selectpicker">
                                                                            <option>ha</option>
                                                                            <option>m²</option>                                                                         
                                                                            </select></p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <label>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Estimar</button>
              </label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para impedir que o botão siga o caminho esperado precisa de usar `.preventDefault()`. Mude o seu código para:

```
$('#enviar').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

e o resto igual.

Porém surge-me uma dúvida. A meu ver tem um erro de lógica aí. Esse botão é um link ou um botão com `type="submit"`? se fôr não devia ser pois é isso que lhe causa o problema e não vejo que queira utilizar a funcionalidade para o qual esse botão é feito. Caso a minha suspeita esteja correta mude o HTML para `<button type="button">etc</button>` e aí não precisa mudar nada no jQuery.

Caso haja aí um `form` que está a ser submetido então tem de mudar para usar AJAX, complementando ao `.preventDefault()` que já sugeri em cima. Mas não vejo isso no seu código ou explicação do problema.

Se colocar o HTML posso melhorar a resposta e ser mais específico.

Comment: Funcionou Sergio, vou editar com o html,pois não entendi o por que ele faz isso,de uma olhada,por favor, e ve se entende

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira ok, o problema é que tem uma `form` na página e `button` sem `type` é o mesmo que `type="submit"` pois essa é a ação por defeito do `button` quando dentro de uma `form`. Se não precisa da `form` (que envia os dados para o servidor) retire-a.

Comment: Entendi Sergio,obrigado pela ajuda e desculpe o incomodo

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira fico contente de ter ajudado! Se a resposta resolveu o problema pode marcar como aceite.